# What do cavity maps really do?

Tags: normal-map

I understand it's used to show more of the micro details in your mesh...  But what I'm confused about is what does it do that Ambient occlusion and a normal can't? The map is just a black and white map, can't you use it as a bump map too?  I don't see why I can't just put everything in the normal map?  What's the point?  But apparently this map is important to show small details...  Wouldn't a high def normal map do the same?

Comment: It's just a more precise form of ambient occlusion meant for really small areas like lava rock or pores. It's "tighter" so to speak. You could probably re-create a similar effect by multiplying your ambient occlusion by a second ambient occlusion that has been clamped by a colorramp that has been set to remove most of any grayscale, and only leave the small "true black" (or close to) areas (white slider moved most of the way to the left side).

Comment: A cavity map is not important to show small details; it is important to *emphasize* small details.  There is not a strong distinction between a cavity map and an AO map, as a cavity map is just an AO map at short distance.  You could use any texture as any other texture, and if it shows what you want to show, you're golden.  Normal maps don't come into play here, even though there is some bad info floating around about cavity maps being the blue channel of a normal map (not remotely true.)  Normal maps will not show occlusion, so a normal map cannot be used to replicate cavity stuff.

Comment: Would you use cavity maps for skin pours than?  That's as micro as I can think of for my projects.